# Shopify error "A store is required" │ Specify the store passing --store={your_store_url} or set the SHOPIFY_FLAG_STORE environment variable

Tags: shopify

I am new to Shopify CLI and I am trying to develop an existing Shopify theme locally in MacOS.

I have installed the Shopify theme kit by `brew tap shopify/shopify` following `brew install shopify-cli`

After that I generated a store password via the Shopify app Theme Kit Access

Then ran the following command with the appropriate details

```
theme get  --password=["your password"] --store= ["your store name"] --themeid=["your theme id"]
```

Files have successfully downloaded into the local folder.

When I tried `shopify theme dev` the following error occurs

```
error ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                              │
│  A store is required                                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Specify the store passing --store={your_store_url} or set the               │
│  SHOPIFY_FLAG_STORE environment variable.                                    │
│
```

Basically, I am trying to run the theme locally and I am facing this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

shopify theme dev --store="storename" --password="shptka_XXXX04d6d833XXXXX23579efaXXXXb6X"

the password comes from the app Theme Access

Hope this helps

ps. I used this command today to login as Shopify CLi has no direct access you must use the app.